# using highcharts with php and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

is anyone ever use hightchart??i want to use hightchart to represent the data retrieve from mysql database..i try look at the example,this is full example:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $(function() {
var seriesOptions = [],
    yAxisOptions = [],
    seriesCounter = 0,
    names = ['MSFT', 'AAPL', 'GOOG'],
    colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;

$.each(names, function(i, name) {

$.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename='+ name.toLowerCase() +'-c.json&callback=?',   function(data) {


        seriesOptions[i] = {
            name: name,
            data: data
        };

        // As we're loading the data asynchronously, we don't know what order it will arrive. So
        // we keep a counter and create the chart when all the data is loaded.
        seriesCounter++;

        if (seriesCounter == names.length) {
            createChart();
        }
    });
});



// create the chart when all data is loaded
function createChart() {

    chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },

        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 4
        },

        yAxis: {
            labels: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return (this.value > 0 ? '+' : '') + this.value + '%';
                }
            },
            plotLines: [{
                value: 0,
                width: 2,
                color: 'silver'
            }]
        },

        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                compare: 'percent'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y}</b> ({point.change}%)<br/>',
            valueDecimals: 2
        },

        series: seriesOptions
    });
}

    });
    </script>
```

the problem is they used this link ("http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename='+ name.toLowerCase() +'-c.json&callback=?") to get the data and which that i cant to view the example how they display the data..
i dont know how the link "http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php" is look like, and how they represent the data.. i want to make my own page that retrieve data from database  and replace the link above with my own php page..
this is working example...http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/compare

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an array of data you want to populate. Then encode the php array to json format using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php). Echo that json string.
Here is a sample code

```
$a[] = 1133740800000;
$a[] = 1133740800000;
$a[] = 1133740800000;
$a[] = 1133740800000;
$a[] = 1133740800000;
$b[] = 405.85;
$b[] = 405.85;
$b[] = 405.85;
$b[] = 405.85;
$b[] = 405.85;

foreach($a as $i => $v)
{
    $cordinates[]= array($v,$b[$i]); 
}

echo (json_encode($cordinates));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: owh,, i will try it first..thank u..if i have a problem later i will come back soon...:)

Comment: How far have you got? There is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/) with a demo.

Comment: with your example above, how if i want to add another array and display another cordinates.. it only shown one line only,,i want make 3 comparison data..

Comment: that was only dummy data... replace the values in the array `$a` & `$b` with your co-ordinates

Answer (score 1):

## solved------------  index file below

```
        <!DOCTYPE HTML>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
                <title>Highcharts Example</title>

                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var chart;
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $.getJSON("map2.php", function(json) {
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                        chart: {
                            renderTo: 'container',
                            type: 'line',
                            marginRight: 130,
                            marginBottom: 25
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Revenue vs. Overhead',
                            x: -20 //center
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: '',
                            x: -20
                        },

                        yAxis: {
                            title: {
                                text: 'Amount'
                            },
                            plotLines: [{
                                value: 0,
                                width: 1,
                                color: '#808080'
                            }]
                        },

                        tooltip: {
                            formatter: function() {
                                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                                    this.x +': '+ this.y;
                            }
                        },
                        legend: {
                            layout: 'vertical',
                            align: 'right',
                            verticalAlign: 'top',
                            x: -10,
                            y: 100,
                            borderWidth: 0
                        },
                        series: json
                    });

                });

            });

        });
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
          <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
          <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

        <div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

            </body>
        </html>
```

## ajax file below

```
    <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
    if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }mysql_select_db("cakephp", $con);
    $sth = mysql_query("SELECT revenue FROM highcharts2");
    $rows = array();
    $rows['name'] = 'revenue';
    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($sth)) {
     $rows['data'][] = $r['revenue'];
    }
    $sth = mysql_query("SELECT overhead FROM highcharts2");
    $rows1 = array();
    $rows1['name'] = 'overhead';
    while($rr = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
    $rows1['data'][] = $rr['overhead'];
    }$result = array();
    array_push($result,$rows);
    array_push($result,$rows1);
    print json_encode($result, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
    mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

## create db like below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `highcharts2` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `month` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `revenue` varchar(225) NOT NULL,
  `overhead` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
)
INSERT INTO `highcharts2` (`id`, `month`, `revenue`, `overhead`) VALUES
(1, 'jan', '23987', '21990'),
(2, 'Feb', '24784', '22363'),
(3, 'Mar', '25899', '21987'),
(4, 'Apr', '25569', '22369'),
(5, 'May', '25599', '22698'),
(6, 'jun', '25577', '21999'),
(7, 'Jul', '24111', '2599'),
(8, 'Aug', '25555', '21988'),
(9, 'sep', '25444', '21981'),
(10, 'oct', '25599', '21988'),
(11, 'nov', '24559', '20142'),
(12, 'dec', '25111', '22222');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using firebug, you can check the response of the ajax, should be a json object